# no repetir resultados de tabla

Tags: sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT DISTINCT
HPNESTANC.ADNINGRES AS ESTANCIA1 , HPNESTANC.HESFECING AS FECHA_INGRESO  FROM HPNESTANC
 WHERE EXISTS
 (SELECT  MAX( HPNESTANC.ADNINGRES), MAX(HPNESTANC.HESFECING) FROM HPNESTANC WHERE  HPNDEFCAM IN(80,237, 238,239,240,241,242,243,244,
245,247,248,249,245,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,256,357)
 )ORDER BY 1
```

pero no quiero que en el resultado me repita esos valores la captura es la siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No debería mostrarte el Null? Que es exactamente lo que no quieres que duplique?

Comment: No quieres que te muestre esos resultados en específico o que te muestre todos los `ESTANCIA1` iguales agrupados en un solo registro?

Comment: @Rafael usa el comando GROUP BY de SQL para que los agrupe

Comment: Quiero q me arroje un solo resultado en estancia 1 que no los repita

Comment: solo quiero un resultado de estancia1 sin agrupar @Killbunny

Comment: Y cual de las FECHA_INGRESO debería mostrarte?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho tendria que mostrar la ultima fecha

Comment: @PatricioMoracho tendria que mostrar un solo registro por estancia1 con su respectiva fecha

Comment: @Rafael checate esto : [max date] (https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/max-date.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que la consulta que tenes actualmente esta correcta, solo la tienes que usar como entrada para otra consulta que agrupe y traiga la maxima fecha.

```
Select ESTANCIA1, Max(FECHA_INGRESO)
from (tu select)
group by ESTANCIA1
```

Podrias no hacer un select es select, haciendo lo siguiente:

```
SELECT 
HPNESTANC.ADNINGRES AS ESTANCIA1 , max(PNESTANC.HESFECING) AS FECHA_INGRESO  FROM HPNESTANC
 WHERE EXISTS
 (SELECT  MAX( HPNESTANC.ADNINGRES), MAX(HPNESTANC.HESFECING) FROM HPNESTANC WHERE  HPNDEFCAM IN(80,237, 238,239,240,241,242,243,244,
245,247,248,249,245,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,256,357)
 )
group by HPNESTANC.ADNINGRES 
ORDER BY 1
```